# Singular VS Plural Words with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code I'm using for a Javascript countdown timer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowTimes1() {
    var now = new Date();
    if (now.getHours() < 6) {
        newVar = 5
    } else if (now.getHours() < 12) {
        newVar = 11
    } else if (now.getHours() < 18) {
        newVar = 17
    } else {
        newVar = 23
    }
    var hrs = newVar - now.getHours();
    var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
    var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
    var str = '';
    str += '<b><a href="discount.php" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:default;"><span style="color:#FF9600;">Limited Time Offer!</span> <span style="color:#489FDC;">' + hrs + ' Hours ' + mins + ' Minutes ' + secs + ' Seconds</span></a></b>';
    document.getElementById('countdownToMidnight').innerHTML = str
}
var _cntDown;

function StopTimes() {
    clearInterval(_cntDown)
}
</script>
```

It works almost perfectly, except for one thing.  It always shows "hours", "minutes", and "seconds" instead of the singular version when there is only 1.  For example, I want it to show "1 second" instead of "1 seconds".

This is the specific part of the code that handles displaying that text:

```
'+hrs+' Hours '+mins+' Minutes '+secs+' Seconds
```

Is there any simple way to fix my code to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Ternary operator` to simplify your job.

Try,

```
'+ hrs +' Hour' + ((hrs>1)?'s':'') +mins+' Minute' + ((mins>1)?'s':'') +secs+' Second' + ((secs>1)?'s':'')
```

Full line code:

```
str += '<b><a href="discount.php" style="text-decoration:none;cursor:default;"><span style="color:#FF9600;">Limited Time Offer!</span> <span style="color:#489FDC;">'+ hrs +' Hour' + ((hrs>1)?'s':'') +mins+' Minute' + ((mins>1)?'s':'') +secs+' Second' + ((secs>1)?'s':'')+ ' Seconds</span></a></b>';
```

Comment: Just tried but then the countdown timer just disappeared from the page :/

Comment: @user2970202 You should have missed something while merging. Just try the updated code.

Comment: @user2970202 Then try changing the condition from `hrs>1` to `hrs===1`

Comment: Tried that and it just shows every with an `s` at the end again.  This is what I currently have:  `'+ hrs +' Hour' + ((hrs===1)?'s ':' ') +mins+' Minute' + ((mins===1)?'s ':' ') +secs+' Second' + ((secs===1)?'s ':' ')+ '`

Comment: @user2970202 Try Like this `((hrs===1)?'':'s')` :)

Comment: Yup that worked, tried it literally 30 seconds before you posted it lol.  I didn't know what I was doing but it made since to switch them since everything was backwards lol.

Answer (score 0):

' + hrs + ' Hours ' + mins + ' Minutes ' + secs + ' Seconds
to become

```
// ...
' + hrs + ' Hour' + (1===hrs) ? ' ' : 's ' 
 + mins + ' Minute' + (1===mins) ? ' ' : 's ' 
 + secs + ' Second' +  (1===secs) ? ' ' : 's' 
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use ternary operator for such trivial case. However it will not work for multiple languages and it will be very difficult to translate your app.

To address such use cases, I’ve implemented a small library that can be used to pluralize words in JavaScript. It transparently uses CLDR database for multiple locales, so it supports almost any language you would like to use. It’s API is very minimalistic and integration is extremely simple. I've called it — [Numerous](https://github.com/betsol/numerous).

Here's a small introductory article on it: «[How to pluralize any word in different languages using JavaScript?](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/f2e5259cab17d55af5d9fa4c2c2baa08)».

Feel free to use it in your project. I will also be glad to receive your feedback on it!